# How to do a proper OUTER JOIN with these three tables? I keep getting all results in the last column, added up

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have three tables:
usuarios (users)
cursosUsuarios (enrollements of each user in a course)
pagos (payments)

**I want to do a list of all users in a given course with the payments added up. For the users that didn't yet paid, they should still appear in the list.**

### These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userEmail char(50) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE cursosUsuarios (
    cursosUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int not null DEFAULT '0'
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE pagos (
    pagoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int null,
    pagoMonto int null COMMENT 'aumont of money paid'
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### This is my query:

```
                       SELECT    
                          usuarios.userID AS userid, 
                          SUM(pagos.pagoMonto) AS total

                        FROM usuarios 
                        RIGHT JOIN cursosUsuarios
                        ON usuarios.userID = cursosUsuarios.userID

                        LEFT JOIN pagos
                        ON pagos.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID

                        WHERE cursosUsuarios.cursoID = 90
                        GROUP BY usuarios.userID, pagos.cursoID
                        ORDER BY usuarios.userID DESC
```

### The expected result is:

```
userid  total   
1   500
2   NULL
3   200
4   100
5   400
6   NULL
7   NULL
8   NULL
9   NULL
10   NULL
```

### The result I get is:

```
userid  total   
1   1200
3   1200
4   1200
5   1200
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I am at work and cannot answer in length now but the SUM occurs after the group by and will occur on each row. NULL's will be excluded. Will work a solution tonight if you get no answer. It has to do with order of operations in sql for aggregates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see how your tables are laid to have a much more accurate result. Since I don't know how the values are laid out, I assumed that you want to SUM based on each userID under the pagos table.

I also don't  understand why you have a RIGHT JOIN and then a LEFT to the tables. I assumed you always want the ID's matching and not just what's stored on CurosUsuarios. Feel free to tweak your JOINS.

```
           SELECT    
                 usuarios.userID AS userid,
                 pagos1.total 
                 FROM usuarios
             LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios ON usuarios.userID = cursosUsuarios.userID
             LEFT JOIN  (
                      SELECT SUM(pagos.pagoMonto) AS total,
                          pagos.cursoID,
                          pagos.userID
                       FROM pagos
                      WHERE pagos.cursoID = ?
                      GROUP BY userID
                    ) pagos1 ON pagos1.userID = cursosUsuarios.userID
        WHERE cursosUsuarios.cursoID = ?
        ORDER BY usuarios.userApellido ASC
```

Comment: I've found the solution and edited the answer in order to paste what worked in case it helps somebody else (your query needed just a couple of tweaks but it point me in the right direction!!). Thanks!